Methods to Interpret Physical Relationships Between Inputs and Output in a Trained ANN Model
I have trained an artificial neural network (ANN) model using PyTorch that accurately predicts a scalar output based on three input tensors with the following shapes:
Input 1: (3600, 3)
Input 2: (10001, 3)
Input 3: (1,)
Output: (1,) float64
The model architecture includes fully connected layers that take flattened and concatenated inputs from these tensors. The model is trained successfully and gives accurate predictions.
I aim to interpret the physical relationships between these input matrices and the output. To find a mathematical relation, that explains the Physics behind how the three inputs affect the output value.

What techniques can be used to understand the contribution of different features in the input matrices to the final prediction?

Are there effective visualization methods to illustrate how the input data relates to the output in a physical context?


I'm relatively new to ANN and is there any specific name for this process? That is extracting the relation from a trained model?
I am seeking guidance on methodologies, tools, and best practices to achieve these goals. Any insights or references to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.
I tried plotting the fc1 layer and here is the result, it is not helping much

